# How to view LINQ to SQL Query results in Messagebox?

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-sql, messagebox

I am running a query with LINQ to SQL. I am trying to output the results into a messagebox, but the messagebox that shows up is displaying the my query rather than the results?

Here is my code

```
var thisQuery = from c in myContext.SpecificTable
                where c.UniqueValue == "\'Z1234\'"
                select new
                {
                c.UniqueValue,
                c.UniqueValueDetails,
                c.UniqueValueType
                };

MessageBox.Show(thisQuery.ToString());
```

I imagine the issue is I can't call thisQuery into a string directly, but I'm not sure how to view the results of my query otherwise?

When I run the above I get a resulting message box that shows:

```
SELECT [t0].[UniqueValue], [t0].[UniqueValueDetails], [t0].[UniqueValueType]

FROM [dbo].[SpecificTable] AS [t0]

WHERE [t0].[UniqueValue] = @p0
```

How can I view my results from the query in the message box?

I also tried storing the entire query result tostring but ended up with the same results:

```
var thisQuery = (from c in myContext.SpecificTable
                where c.UniqueValue == "\'Z1234\'"
                select new
                {
                c.UniqueValue,
                c.UniqueValueDetails,
                c.UniqueValueType
                }).ToString();

MessageBox.Show(thisQuery);
```

I tried looking this up and have read a handful of threads, but I can't seem to word the question in a way that has yielded results.

Comment: Well, first I guess you need to decide what you want that message box to actually display.  Your query returns a collection of records.  How are you going to represent that collection as a string?

Comment: @David - fair enough. I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to format my results whether it be by selecting the specific fields in the query as displayed, or if I can just select 'c' and later format with calls to those values I wanted. In my example I was attempting to force the formatting in the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` can show a string as a message, your query returns tabular data. You can concatenate all the results of query and then show it in `MessageBox` like:

```
var messageString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                               thisQuery.Select(r=> string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}"
                                                    , r.UniqueValue
                                                    , r.UniqueValueDetails
                                                    ,r.UniqueValueType));

MessageBox.Show(messageString);
```

Its better if you use `Grid` for displaying records from query.

Comment: In your example would you still need the initial query as I had setup? I don't fully understand how your example calls the appropriate table to query from?

Comment: @FuzzEvans: This code is building on your code.  You still need to define the variable `thisQuery`, which your code already does.